# Show x-axis on Matplotlib - Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two arrays that i am graphing like this

```
dates = [datetime.date(2015, 11, 22), datetime.date(2015, 11, 23), datetime.date(2015, 11, 24)]
points = [3L, 1L, 2L]
```

And then I plot like this

```
plt.plot(dates, points, 'r-o')
plt.xticks(rotation=70)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('test.pdf')
```

Which produces a graph like this

[image]

But i don't want the times to appear, I want to dates to appear and I have an array of dates, not date times or times, so what is the x axis showing times?

How can I get it to be like this on the x axis `2015-11-22, 2015-11-23, 2015-11-24`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Result of code]

Try this :

```
dates = [datetime.date(2015, 11, 22), datetime.date(2015, 11, 23), datetime.date(2015, 11, 24)]
points = [3L, 1L, 2L]
x = [x for x in range(0,len(points))]
plt.plot(points, 'r-o')
plt.xticks(rotation=70)
plt.xticks(x,dates)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('test.pdf')
```

I hope it's help

Comment: I still get no labels on x axis

Comment: Not sure if this makes a difference but when I do `print dates` I get this `[datetime.date(2015, 11, 22), datetime.date(2015, 11, 23), datetime.date(2015, 11, 24)]` like in the question and when i do `print dates[0]` I get `2015-11-22`

Comment: No, it's normal, stringification of datetime.date is what you have when you try to print a date with the print function. Try to remove rotation from xticks. Don't forget to close open pdf files (to correct handle rewrite of it)
I know it's not a answer, but code works here ;)
Try to copy/paste my code just to see. Try to do a plt.show() instead of plt.savefig() to see quickly the result. Never forget to close windows...